# Access violation reading location 0x04106011, I can't tell where is wrong

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, runtime-error

```
; 2.Linking Array Items
.data
    start dword 1
    chars1 byte 'H','A','C','E','B','D','F','G'
    links DWORD 0,4,5,6,2,3,7,0
    target byte lengthof chars1 dup (?)
.code
    mov edi, 0
    mov ecx, lengthof chars1
    L2:
    mov esi,start  ; esi=1
    mov al, chars1[esi]  ;al='A', error report on this line
    mov target[edi*type target], al   ;target = 'A'
    mov ebx, links[esi] ; ebx=links[1]=4
    mov start, ebx
    loop L2
```

I've been stuck on this error for a few days and I didn't know how to fix it. Can someone teach me how to fix it?

Comment: `links[esi]` <-- `DWORD`s are 4 bytes each, so you need to use `links[esi*4]`

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what instruction faults, as a basic first step!!  Without a debugger, you're wasting your time (and everyone else's).  If it's not one of the instructions in the loop, then it's probably when execution falls into whatever garbage bytes are after, since you don't have any exit system call.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for asm debugging tips.